# Gtk::MessageDialog Run throws a segmentation fault

Tags: linux, gtk, gtkmm

Hi I'm trying to show an error mesaage using a dialogbox. However when I run the code I get segmentation fault.

Here's the function:

```
void ShowErrorMessage(string message)
{
  Gtk::MessageDialog dialog(message,true,Gtk::MESSAGE_ERROR,Gtk::BUTTONS_CLOSE,true);
  dialog.run();
}
```

I try to open a file, if the file can not be open I wanna show this error box, however i keep running into segmentation fault.

Comment: There's really not enough context here to figure it out. What is the stack trace when you get the segfault?

Comment: Are you using chars other than the ASCII ones in `message`? If this is the case, ensure to encode them in UTF8.

Comment: hmm..I guess I can try that...how do i encode them in UTF8?

Comment: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-basics-ustring.html.en
If this is the problem, you should basically use Glib::locale_to_utf8().

Comment: Thanks that didn't solve the problem, I guess it's a problem with the dialogbox not having a parent window 'cuz i'm calling it before my main window shows. What do you think ?

Comment: You can also show a dialog without any parent window, there is no dark magic involved. My guess is your problem is of totally different nature: providing a minimal test case exposing the problem would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to call `new` on the dialog or is that a static class? See [here](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkMessageDialog.html) for the document on this, which is leading me to think that's why your code segfaults...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Hi tom - no I dont need to call new..i'm using gtkmm

Answer (score 0):

maybe you did not added this line at the begining?

```
Gtk::Main_kit(argc, argv);
```

Comment: I do have this line added, before I call the error message function.